# Stove efficiency

Tags: canister-stoves

The [Jet Boil Minimo](http://www.jetboil.com/Products/MiniMo-Cooking-System-Carbon/) is supposed to be an efficient cooking system that uses [FluxRing technology](http://www.jetboil.com/Accessories/-8L-Spare-Cup/):

> FluxRing® technology makes it possible to heat a conveniently shaped vessel with extremely high efficiency. This patented technology captures the heat of the burner and directs it into the contents of the FluxRing® cup, rather than into the air as waste.​​

The [MSR Pocket Rocket](http://www.cascadedesigns.com/msr/stoves/rapid-cooking/pocketrocket/product) is a classic and minimalist canister stove. I would like to compare the efficiency/total weight of these two stoves for the use case of boiling 2 cups of water once a day.

To make the systems comparable the MSR stove needs a pot (lets assume something like the [Evernew Ti Ultralight Pot 600ml](http://www.evernewamerica.com/ultralight-series/)) and a pot cozy. The Jetboil setup is listed as weighing 415 g while the MSR stove, pot, and cozy would be about 240 g.

I would assume if you are out for a single day the MSR setup wins since you need to carry a single canister in both cases. Is there a break point where the Jetboil fuel savings offsets the heavier weight?

Comment: as long as you are not hiking for long enough to need a second canister, you'd rather have the canister empty _faster_ to carry less with every passing day. Which with 2 cups per day is well above a full week.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have several considerations to think about.

Altitude affects water's boiling point

Temperature affects fuel efficiency

Wind affects the stove's efficiency

You'll need to make simultaneous comparisons between the two stoves, and do it in all conditions and at the altitudes you intend to use them.

In the end, you can't go wrong with either.  The MSR is lighter, but you'll want a wind shield.

Answer (score 1):

A 100 gram canister of Jetpower fuel boils up to 10-12 liters of water according to the web site
Make it 10 grams / liter

Let'd say it is twice as efficient how many liters are the break even
And it is probably not twice as efficient

What is the break even point?

415 + L * 10 =  240 + L * 20
415 - 240 = L * 10
17.6 L = 74 cups = 37 days

Comment: I think you are forgetting that the fuel comes in fixed sized canisters of different weights which makes the problem harder. Further, why do you assume the Jetboil is twice as efficient?

Comment: The MSR specifications say 16 liters boiled per 227-g canister.

Comment: @StrongBad I know it comes in sizes.   At 100 gram is about 20 days.   I take twice as efficient as a data point to get a worse case.   Why in the word are you even considering 45 days?   That much food is not realistic.

Comment: @StrongBad I don't know how long you are staying.  Just add up the number of liters you need and calculate.   If the MSR get 16 liters boiled per 227-g canister then you would need 110 day to break even.

Comment: Anecdotal data (having been on a trip with other campers using a Pocket Rocket), the JetBoil is about twice as fast to boil water as the MSR. Measured indoors, a JetBoil takes about 6g of fuel to heat 1/2L of 34 F water to a boil.

Comment: "Let'd say it is twice as efficient" why? don't you have numbers on the efficiency of the pocket rocket?

Comment: according to this test: http://thru-hiker.com/articles/pocket_rocket_test.php the pocket rocket gets you about 28 cups (~6.6L) for a 3.5 oz (100g) canister, using about .3oz per 2 cups. It also says that the final .4oz of gas could not be used